# Can't get url by QNetworkAccessManager (result differs what I see in my browser)

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I use QT 4.8.2 for my project.
My problem is what QTNetworkAccess can't get my url (or decode it) correctly.
If I paste my url to browser, I see what result in browser differs what I see in result (QNetworkreply).

This is example url I need to get:
* https://myhost/folder/folder/rss?cn1%5B0%5D=Web%2C+Mobile+%26+Software+Dev&amp;cn2%5B0%5D=Web+Development

or, without urlencode:
** https://myhost/folder/folder/rss?cn1[]=Web%2C+Mobile+%26+Software+Dev&cn2[]=Web+Development

I try to pass QUrl as * and **.

This is my code to get:

```
networkAccess = new QNetworkAccessManager();
connect (networkAccess, SIGNAL (finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT (h_networkAccess(QNetworkReply*)));

request = new QNetworkRequest(QUrl(settings->get()->rss_link));
request->setRawHeader("User-Agent",      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0");
request->setRawHeader("Accept",          "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request->setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");
request->setRawHeader("Connection",      "keep-alive");
if (settings->get()->cookie != "")
    request->setRawHeader("Cookie",      settings->get()->cookie.toAscii()); 

networkAccess->get(*request);
```

Maybe, my problem is "+" symbol in url ... But I don't know.
I can provide full link what I need to test.

Please, help.

Comment: Unrelated comment: You're leaking the request object. There's no need to create it on the heap, create it on the stack instead.

Comment: What is returned by he QNAM? an error?

Comment: QNAM returned the data without error, but, I think, without parameters (i.e. I have same result in browser when I get  https://myhost/folder/folder/rss).

Comment: No leaks, I delete the pointer when I use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url is already encoded, use [`QUrl::fromEncoded`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromEncoded)
From the doc:

> Parses input and returns the corresponding QUrl. input is assumed to
>   be in encoded form, containing only ASCII characters.

Comment: What is the output of `qDebug() << QUrl(settings->get()->rss_link)`? and did you try to use other tools like cURL to see where the problem is?

Comment: url I need to grab is https://www.upwork.com/jobs/rss?cn1[]=Web%2C+Mobile+%26+Software+Dev&cn2[]=Web+Development&t[]=0&t[]=1&dur[]=0&dur[]=1&dur[]=13&dur[]=26&dur[]=none&wl[]=10&wl[]=30&wl[]=none&tba[]=0&tba[]=1-9&tba[]=10-&exp[]=1&exp[]=2&exp[]=3&amount[]=Min&amount[]=Max&sortBy=s_ctime+desc . for example. If get it via QNAM, i see what get parameters is ignored.

Comment: I use VS 2010, qDebug isn't work for me. But, if I add QString aa = QUrl(settings->get()->rss_link).toString(); in aa variable I see the same as rss_link (rss ling is QString too), so, conversion to QUrl and back is correct.